# Find item in another array and remove matched item from array

Tags: javascript

I have two array with records like below:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

Now I want to remove matching element from Cars1 so at the end my Cars1 array will be like below :

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

 for (var i = 0; i < cars1.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cars.length; j++) {
                    if (cars1[i] == cars[j]) {
                        cars1.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
console.log(cars1)
```

**Expected Output :**

```
 var cars1 = [];
```

I am not getting expected output.

Comment: I don't like the fact that most answers here aren't even trying to understand OP's bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some items because the deleted item is replaced with the next one when you iterate. Just loop the other way, with *i* decreasing:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

 for (var i=cars1.length; i--;) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cars.length; j++) {
                    if (cars1[i] == cars[j]) {
                        cars1.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
console.log(cars1)
```

Note that you don't really need an explicit double loop. One of the possible alternatives would be to use `indexOf`. Another one (more efficient in case of big arrays) would be to put the content of cars1 into an instance of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). And if you don't need to keep the same array, there's also [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of course.

Here's how it would be with a set and reduce (a very efficient solution when cars arrays are big):

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
 
var set = cars.reduce((s,c) => s.add(c), new Set);
cars1 = cars1.filter(c => !set.has(c)); 
console.log(cars1);
```

And for antique browsers:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
 
var set = cars.reduce(function(s,c){
     s[c] = true;
     return s;
}, Object.create(null));
cars1 = cars1.filter(function(c){
     return !set[c];
}); 
console.log(cars1);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.I am having 1000 of records in both array so what do you think which approach will be more suitable??

Comment: @Learning In this case use the set. I'll update to show you how to do it

Comment: Sorry to bug you again but this set and reduce works in all browser and also old browser??

Comment: Starting from IE11. It must be slightly adapted to cover older versions of Internet Explorer. Do you want to see that version too ? (edit: done)

Comment: If i have got a chance to upvote your answer 10 times then i would have defintely.Thanks you so much and in your last answer you
are assigning output to cars variable instead of car1

Comment: Can you please tell me why set is more efficient then loop.actually i am not that good with javascript so trying to learn things that is why asking you

Comment: An instance of Set, or an plain object used as a set, is optimized for looking at properties by name. The default structure behind is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and it's further optimized by good engines like V8, especially when it's reused.

Comment: This is the reason of asking question on SO because i know you guys would always have best solution of what i will do.If i would have done
this in my way then definetely i would have crash user browser with loop in case of thousand of records :)

Answer (score 3):

Using a simple functional approach to save some space and make it cleaner I would recommend using `Array.prototype.filter` in combination with `Array.prototype.indexOf` like this:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "VW"];

cars1 = cars1.filter(car => cars.indexOf(car) < 0)

console.log(cars1)
```

The `filter` method calls the passed callback for each element, if the callback returns `false` the element won't be returned if returned `true` the element gets returned. Notice that the `filter` method returns a new array, and does not modify the current one! Thanks to @denys-séguret for mentioning it!

`indexOf` returns the index of the passed element. If not found `-1` is returned. Thats why whe filter all elements out, where the index is `< 0`, only returning elements that are not already in the `cars` array.

Comment: Please note this important difference: the original array isn't updated. It may matter, depending on OP's need (arrays are often shared). You also don't explain OP's bug.

Comment: Yes! Thats why I'm reassigning `cars1` to the return value of the filter call.

Comment: Yes but this isn't enough when the array is shared (which is the most usual reason for using splice)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to do is called `difference`. The opposite is `intersection`.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Skoda"]; 

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 

function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x) === -1)
}

function intersec(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x) > -1)
}

console.log(
  diff(cars, cars1),
  intersec(cars, cars1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting wrong result, because with every `slice()`, elements inside are changing their index. So after the first loop, `Volvo` will get `0` index and actually item with `0` index was already processed, so the function won't operate it. That's why it stays inside after function.

I suggest you to use `Array#filter`.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
    cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
    
    var result = cars.filter(v => cars1.indexOf(v) == -1);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first call to cars1.splice(i, 1), the cars1 has one less element, hence it doesn't make much sense to continue with the outer loop.
To make the code cleaner I`d suggest to use indexOf instead of the inner loop.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var cars1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  var carPositionInCars1 = cars1.indexOf(cars[i]);
  if (carPositionInCars1 != -1) {
    cars1.splice(carPositionInCars1, 1);
  }
}
console.log(cars1);
```

Comment: Pplease provide some information on what your code actually does. Where did you improve the OPs code, what did he do wrong... it is hard to learn just from a few random lines of code that are thrown towards you without any explanation.